# When will GTK improvements land in Maverick?

Tags: 10.10, gtk, csd

I want to see CSD(Client Side Decorations),Windicators and RGBA.

Comment: This seems to me quite off-topic here. Please instead file a bug on launchpad specifying which release of GTK you would like to see in Ubuntu.

Comment: No,it is not from upstream but from Canonical and it introduces the above mentioned features.It is completely related to Ubuntu 10.10 Development release.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will land in Maverick when it is ready. No sooner, no later.

Comment: Brilliant answer!